# visual studio enterprise (not available xamarin profiler)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I installed last version of visual studio 2017 enterprise yesterday. and buy production key and apply it successfully, 
But there is no xamarin profiler tools and release options like bundle assembly to native code and ...

[image: xamarin profiler not available]

Comment: install the profiler: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/profiler/#Download_and_Install

Comment: I've installed it; now the release option like AOT and bundle assembly to native code are not there

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, VS2017 Enterprise with license and Bundle assemblies into native code is no longer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I had to reset factory my windows; I think the reason of problem was new limitation that Microsoft have made for Persian and maybe some others. After renew the windows and before new installation visual studio, Microsoft store didn't work; I've changed region from Iran to United State then Store Works correctly, and after that I installed VS and now it works.
We are Persian and we don't have any relation with government.

you can follow this problem from [Visual Studio Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/199589/problem-with-visual-studio-enterprise-there-is-no.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have a quick solution for the Bundle assemblies into native code, so I change my android project at this line:

```
<BundleAssemblies>true</BundleAssemblies> 
<!--BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies-->
```